# Creating child within xml file

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Hey, guys. I want to ask if someone can give me an example of creating child through xml. I mean creating custom components through xml (for every xml tag you create your own custom component and then add it as a child to the stage). I hope is it clear enough... :)

Comment: Um, isn't that called MXML? :)

Comment: You can use any kind of component you want, don't complicate your life, I'm not pretentious :) I appreciate any assistance you can offer

Comment: well, no my friend :) I must do it in AS3.. I have a huge xml file which contains <frame> tags, and every <frame> tag contains <text> tags and so on... So, I've got to create custom components for each one of the tags, and then add it as a child to the stage...

Answer (score 0):

Answered a similar question a while ago, might help :

[Actionscript 3 : Creating variable objects and assigning class from parsed XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727447/actionscript-3-creating-variable-objects-and-assigning-class-from-parsed-xml-fi/728013#728013)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. However nobody here is going to write your entire program for you, sorry. If you get stuck at a specific point, then you can post a specific question and get some more usable answers.